# Should Dashboard and REST API be on the same express app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, server

I am working on a project I currently have a website(React.js), dashboard and a REST api. I have the dashboard and the REST api on the same express app. Is it better to have them split like making an express app just for the dashboard and another one for the API?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the same api, but the react bundle can be split.  [React docs Code-Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html).  [Good youtube tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mQbxF-_S-M). If you are not already doing that.